# Rails: Prepopulate Ajax select in edit form

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, select

I have a form of a model, the form has 2 selects, one is for State and the other is for City, of course the City select is filled using ajax when you select a state, Im having problems when showing the selected values in edit form, this is the form:

```
#Im just showing you the section where the selects are.
<div class="small-4 columns state-select">
        <%= f.label :state, 'Departamento' %>
        <%= f.select :state, options_for_select(states_with_default.collect { |key, value|
            [value.titleize, key] }, f.object.state) %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns city-select">
        <%= f.label :city, 'Ciudad' %>
        <%= f.select :city, options_for_select([], 0) %>
    </div>
```

I have this coffee script code that updates the cities select when a state is selected and also when the page loads it looks for all the state selects (they can be 1 or more it is a nested form) and updates the cities for each state select:

```
$ ->
  updateCitiesOferts = ($state_input) ->
    console.log $state_input
    $input_city = $state_input.parents().first().next().find('select')
    $.getJSON('/cities/' + $state_input.val(), (data) ->
      $input_city.empty()
      if not $.inArray('orders', window.location.pathname.split( '/' ))
        all_cities_option = '<option value="all">Todo el departamento</select>'
        $input_city.append all_cities_option
      for i in data
        opt = "<option value=\"#{i}\">#{i}</option>"
        $input_city.append opt
    )
  $(document).on 'change', '.state-select select', ->
    updateCitiesOferts $(@)

  for state_input in $('.state-select select')
    updateCitiesOferts $(state_input)
```

Well this code works ok, however when I go to the edit page the cities select is updated with the last selected state but I do not know how to get the selected city from the model =/, I need to show the selected state and also the selected city. So far it loads the list of cities for the last selected state but does not detect the selected city from the model, how to do this?

#### Update

Well as you requested here is a visualization of what I say above.

- When you go to the edit page you will see the last selected state but not the last selected city:

[image: Actual result]

- I need to see the last selected city in the edit form:

[image: Expected result]

Note: 'Seleccionar' is the default option, it is equivalent to "-Select-" in english.

Comment: Well it seems anybody want to help me =(

Comment: Are you using coffeescript?

Comment: maybe you should add some pictures, with expected result and actual result?

Comment: what do you mean by *"I do not know how to get the selected city from the model"*

Comment: check the question I added images at the end

Comment: ah I understand. so you actually want the selected city (from database) to be rendered by default (because this is edit form so your data is already there), am I right?

Comment: Yes I do not know how to do this since the cities are rendered through Ajax, depending of the selected State...

Comment: I see, trying to help you now ;)

Comment: @SsouLlesS please show me your `CitiesController` and City model and State model. I can't help if I don't know the structure of your application. Where and how you store selected city and selected state? And this is the `edit` form of what model?

Comment: Cities and States are not models in my app, Im using this gem for get the values and populate the selects: https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state selected City and State are stored for the Orders model, this is a checkout form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95763/discussion-between-long-nguyen-and-ssoulless).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your form:

```
#Im just showing you the section where the selects are.
<div class="small-4 columns state-select">
        <%= f.label :state, 'Departamento' %>
        <%= f.select :state, options_for_select(states_with_default.collect { |key, value|
            [value.titleize, key] }, f.object.state) %>
</div>
<div class="small-4 columns city-select">
    <%= f.label :city, 'Ciudad' %>
    <%= f.select :city, options_for_select([], 0), {}, { "data-selected" => f.object.city } %>
</div>
```

Now the select of city will have attribute `data-selected="YOUR_SELECTED_VALUE"`

Update your coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  updateCitiesOferts = ($state_input) ->
    console.log $state_input
    $input_city = $state_input.parents().first().next().find('select')
    $.getJSON('/cities/' + $state_input.val(), (data) ->
      $input_city.empty()
      if not $.inArray('orders', window.location.pathname.split( '/' ))
        all_cities_option = '<option value="all">Todo el departamento</select>'
        $input_city.append all_cities_option
      for i in data
        opt = if i == $input_city.data("selected")
          "<option value=\"#{i}\" selected=\"selected\">#{i}</option>"
        else
          "<option value=\"#{i}\">#{i}</option>"
        $input_city.append opt
    )
  $(document).on 'change', '.state-select select', ->
    updateCitiesOferts $(@)

  for state_input in $('.state-select select')
    updateCitiesOferts $(state_input)
```

#### Update

Fixed syntax error in the select_tag of city

Comment: Amazing, a custom data attribute is the key for get this done!, I let you know, thank you very much

Comment: cool, I'm happy to know that I can make you understand the concept. I'm looking forward to hear the result from you ;)